# How to use Fastapi to handle multiple files upload using axios

Tags: python, file-upload, axios, fastapi

This is my HTML file:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="uploading_files" type="file" multiple><br><br>
        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And JavaScript:

```
async function ajax_post(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let data = new FormData();
            console.log(e.target[0].files);
            data.append('files', e.target[0].files);

            await axios.post("/uploadfiles", data, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
            });
        }

(function () {
            console.log("Document Ready.");
            document.getElementById("uploadForm").addEventListener("submit", ajax_post);
})();
```

Finally fastapi script:

```
@app.post("/uploadfiles")
async def catch_file(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    print("="*126)
    for file in files:
        file_fullname = file.filename.split(".")
        file_type = file_fullname[-1]
        print(f"Filename: {file.filename}")
        if len(file_fullname) > 1:
            print(f"File type: {file_type}")
        else:
            print("File type: No File type inputed")
        print("="*126)
```

But I don’t understand why I still got an error on server display `INFO:     127.0.0.1:55302 - "POST /uploadfiles HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity` 
And error on browser: [image]

I had followed the document of Fastapi but still got that error, where have I done wrong?

By the way, I’ve been able to handle single file upload using `async def catch_file(files: UploadFile = File(...)):`

Comment: In the response body, you should have a error explanation. Can you post that one as well?

Comment: It occurs the same error message. @lsabi

Comment: I know, but in the body of the response, there should be something written in json as explanation. Can you post that one?